# Wordpress custom query function AJAX callback returns 0

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

This function is in functions.php but only returns 0 from the AJAX callback. I can't figure out what I need to do to make it work correctly.

```
function CaseStudiesAjaxFunction() {
    global $post;

    $verticle = $_GET["verticle"];
    $product = $_GET["product"];
    $source = $_GET["source"];
    $args = array(
            'posts_per_page' => '12',
            'tag' => array( $verticle, $product, $source)
            );
    $query = new WP_Query($args);
    $matching_posts = array();
    if ($query->have_posts()) : while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
    the_post_thumbnail();
    the_title();
    endwhile;
    endif;
    wp_reset_query();
    die();
}
```

Here is the Jquery AJAX

```
function filterCaseStudies() {
    var data = ($('#case-studies-form').serialize());
    alert(data);
    var request = $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: case_studies_ajax_script.ajaxurl,
        dataType: 'text',
        data: data + "&action=CaseStudiesAjaxFunction"
        });
request.done(function( data ){
$('.case-studies-container').html( data );
    console.log("Request success: " + data);
});
request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
    alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
});
```

The data seems to be passing from the form correctly as I can echo back the variables and the AJAX callback sees them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeing a `'0'` response from `admin-ajax.php` likely because you have not registered the AJAX action hooks for this function.

To properly register your function for the AJAX call you need to use the action hook [`wp_ajax_*`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action)) for functions available to the admin, and [`wp_ajax_nopriv_*`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_nopriv_(action)) to make it available on the front end.

In your JavaScript the AJAX call is not set up properly - `done()` and `success()` were deprecated in jQuery 1.8. You should use the "complete", "success" and "error" callbacks instead.

Using a `POST` is the recommended way of handling AJAX requests in WordPress. Since this is a unique request, there is no reason to call `wp_reset_query()`.

From a personal preference I would return JSON rather than just dumping the values using `the_*` functions. Not a bad idea to check `isset()` on your form values to make sure you don't have any undefined index errors. Also because I'm a little OCD, it should be "vertical" and not "verticle" :)

**PHP**

```
function CaseStudiesAjaxFunction() {
    global $post;

    $vertical = isset( $_GET["vertical"] )? $_GET["vertical"] : '';
    $product = isset( $_GET["product"] )? $_GET["product"] : '';
    $source = isset( $_GET["source"] )? $_GET["source"] : '';
    $args = array(
            'posts_per_page' => '12',
            'tag' => array( $verticle, $product, $source)
            );
    $query = new WP_Query($args);
    if ($query->have_posts()) : while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
        the_post_thumbnail();
        the_title();
    endwhile; endif;
    die();
}
// Add the ajax hooks for admin
add_action( 'wp_ajax_CaseStudiesAjaxFunction', 'CaseStudiesAjaxFunction' );
// Add the ajax hooks for front end
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_CaseStudiesAjaxFunction', 'CaseStudiesAjaxFunction' );
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function filterCaseStudies(){
    var data = $('#case-studies-form').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: case_studies_ajax_script.ajaxurl,
        dataType: 'text',
        data: data + "&action=CaseStudiesAjaxFunction",
        complete: function( xhr, status ){
            console.log("Request complete: " + status);
        },
        error: function( xhr, status, errorThrown ){
            console.log("Request failed: " + status);
        },
        success: function( data, status, xhr ){
            console.log("Request success: " + data);
            // change the html 
            $('.case-studies-container').html( data );
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. I did have the hooks in previously. I tried your code verbatim and the response is empty.

Comment: ..and that's not OCD, I just can't spell.

Comment: It's possible that the query is actually returning nothing. I need to look into this and get back.

Comment: This works thanks so much! One caveat, for multiple tags I needed to use this line instead.. 'tag_slug__and' => array( $vertical, $product, $source)

Answer (score 0):

It returns 0 because the [admin-ajax.php](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php) file ends with `die('0')`.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Any suggestions how to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

When I have done WP Ajax calls in the past, I make sure to `echo json_encode()` all the data into a nicely formatted JSON response, then call `die()` after.  Instead of using functions that print or echo (`the_title()`) you can include them in a variable you return (`$title = get_the_title()`).

You can return all the post information and html in an array, encode it as JSON, then decode:

```
function ajax_call(){
    // Run a loop
    $return['code'] = 100;
    $return['content'] = get_the_content(); //etc, etc
    // End loop
    echo json_encode($return);
    die();
}
```

Comment: JSON is simply a way to encapsulate data, making it easier (in many cases) to transfer properly formatted data.  It's just the way I have worked with AJAX calls.

Comment: I know what JSON is, and it's what I would use if this were my code, but if you check out the example the `the_*` functions are being used to just dump the values to the response and then the AJAX uses `html()` to update the content of a DOM element.

Comment: You're right - that's why I should have mentioned that using functions that return the data instead of echo is the way to go.  However, your answer does a good job of summing this up.

Comment: As an example of when JSON might not be appropriate - let's say you have an "activity feed" like Facebook that you want to update 200 rows at a time. It would be more efficient to construct the HTML on the server and pass it through directly so that the JavaScript engine in the browser doesn't have to parse it.

Comment: If JSON makes things easier I'm open to it.

Comment: I think we all agree that JSON is better :) Pretty sure your original issue is that you don't have the `wp_ajax_*` hooks (see my answer) but you can combine with this one to have it all.